# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\editar-anuncio.php on line 68

Tags: php

Minha linha 68 ta assim.

```
<option value="0"<?php echo ($info['estado']=='0')?'selected="selected"';'';?>>Não Pago</option>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla. Mas vou deixar uma resposta.

Comment: Você colocou um `;` no operador ternário, mas o ternário prevê `:`. No lugar de escrever `?:`, você escreveu `?;`

Answer (score 1):

Como não posso testar nesse momento por está em celular, vou deixar duas opções abaixo:

Opção 1:

```
<option value="0" <?php echo ($info['estado']=='0')?' selected ="selected"' : ''; ?>>Não Pago</option>
```

Opção 2:

```
<?php
if($info['estado']=='0') $select = ' selected="selected"'; else $select = "";
?>
<option value="0"<?php echo $select; ?>>Não Pago</option>
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: Na opção 2, não faltou um espaço entre o `value="0"` e o conteúdo da variável `$select`? Na minha leitura, na caso da comparação ser verdadeira, vai ter como saída `value="0"selected="selected"`

Comment: Isso não é problema, mas editei ai e coloquei o espaço.

Comment: Se minha resposta ti ajudou, marque como resolvida por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que é isso que você quer:

```
<?php if ($info['estado']=='0') {?> 
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Não Pago</option>
<?php } else { ?>
    <option value="0">Não Pago</option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Eu creio que essa solução que você apresentou agora é muito verbosa. Prefiro uma concisão maior, menos repetição... E também o PHP oferece uma sintaxe mais amigável para fazer esses blocos no meio do HTML, `if (cond):`, `else:`, `endif`

Comment: Muito obrigado.